# Clearfix on blogger widget

Tags: blogger, clearfix

I recently added a new widget on my blog, but it seems that a line

```
document.write('<li class="clearfix">');if(showpostthumbnails==true)
```

causes some extra empty space under the link. Deleting the whole line removes link separators and the whole thing doesn't look as it should. Is there any way to fix it? There are no images in the widget although the code was made to show thumbnails. I'm a greenhorn, figuring out that it's caused by "clearfix" took me several hours...

In case it's needed, here's the whole widget

```css
<style>
    /* Recent posts by labels
    --------------------------------- */ 
 img.label_thumb{
display:none!important;
}

 #label_with_thumbs { display: block;
width: 100%;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: center;    /* center aligns text in sidebar */
margin: 0px 0;    /* White space between links */
padding: 0px 0;    /* Padding for colored background */
color: #444444;    /* Link Color */
background-color: #f3f3f3;    /* Background Color */
font-family: "verdana";     /* Link Font */
text-transform: uppercase;    /* Link case. Options are uppercase, lowercase, none, capitalize. */
font-style: normal;    /* Font Style. Options are normal and italics. */
font-weight: normal;    /* Font weight. Options include: light, normal, bold, */
letter-spacing: 1px;    /* Space between letters */
font-size: 12px;   /* Font Size. */
}

#label_with_thumbs li{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;    /* center aligns text in sidebar */
    margin: 0px 0;    /* White space between links */
    padding: 12px 0;    /* Padding for colored background */
 color: #444444;    /* Link Color */
    background-color: #f3f3f3;    /* Background Color */
font-family: "verdana";     /* Link Font */
text-transform: uppercase;    /* Link case. Options are uppercase, lowercase, none, capitalize. */
font-style: normal;    /* Font Style. Options are normal and italics. */
font-weight: normal;    /* Font weight. Options include: light, normal, bold, */
letter-spacing: 1px;    /* Space between letters */
font-size: 12px;   /* Font Size. */
}

#label_with_thumbs a:visited {
             text-decoration: none;
    color: black;}
#label_with_thumbs a:link {
    display: block;
   width: 100%;
vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;    /* center aligns text in sidebar */
    margin: 0px 0;    /* White space between links */
    padding: 12px 0;    /* Padding for colored background */
 color: #444444;    /* Link Color */
    background-color: #f3f3f3;    /* Background Color */
font-family: "verdana";     /* Link Font */
text-transform: uppercase;    /* Link case. Options are uppercase, lowercase, none, capitalize. */
font-style: normal;    /* Font Style. Options are normal and italics. */
font-weight: normal;    /* Font weight. Options include: light, normal, bold, */
letter-spacing: 1px;    /* Space between letters */
font-size: 12px;   /* Font Size. */}

#label_with_thumbs a { text-transform: none;}
#label_with_thumbs a:hover {  color: #ffffff;   /* Link hover color */
    background-color: #386696;    /* Background Color */
}


</style>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
function labelthumbs(json){document.write('<ul id="label_with_thumbs">');for(var i=0;i<numposts;i++){var entry=json.feed.entry[i];var posttitle=entry.title.$t;var posturl;if(i==json.feed.entry.length)break;for(var k=0;k<entry.link.length;k++){if(entry.link[k].rel=='replies'&&entry.link[k].type=='text/html'){var commenttext=entry.link[k].title;var commenturl=entry.link[k].href;}
if(entry.link[k].rel=='alternate'){posturl=entry.link[k].href;break;}}var thumburl;try{thumburl=entry.media$thumbnail.url;}catch(error)
{s=entry.content.$t;a=s.indexOf("<img");b=s.indexOf("src=\"",a);c=s.indexOf("\"",b+5);d=s.substr(b+5,c-b-5);if((a!=-1)&&(b!=-1)&&(c!=-1)&&(d!="")){thumburl=d;}else thumburl='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-zP87C2q9yog/UVopoHY30SI/AAAAAAAAE5k/AIyPvrpGLn8/s1600/picture_not_available.png';}
var postdate=entry.published.$t;var cdyear=postdate.substring(0,4);var cdmonth=postdate.substring(5,7);var cdday=postdate.substring(8,10);var monthnames=new Array();monthnames[1]="Jan";monthnames[2]="Feb";monthnames[3]="Mar";monthnames[4]="Apr";monthnames[5]="May";monthnames[6]="June";monthnames[7]="July";monthnames[8]="Aug";monthnames[9]="Sept";monthnames[10]="Oct";monthnames[11]="Nov";monthnames[12]="Dec";
document.write('<li class="clearfix">');if(showpostthumbnails==true)
document.write('<strong><a href="'+posturl+'" target ="_top">'+posttitle+'</a></strong>');if("content"in entry){var postcontent=entry.content.$t;}
else
    if("summary"in entry){var postcontent=entry.summary.$t;}
    else var postcontent="";var re=/<\S[^>]*>/g;postcontent=postcontent.replace(re,"");if(showpostsummary==true){if(postcontent.length<numchars){document.write('');document.write(postcontent);document.write('');}
    else{document.write('');postcontent=postcontent.substring(0,numchars);var quoteEnd=postcontent.lastIndexOf(" ");postcontent=postcontent.substring(0,quoteEnd);document.write(postcontent+'...');document.write('');}}
    var towrite='';var flag=0;document.write('<br>');if(showpostdate==true){towrite=towrite+monthnames[parseInt(cdmonth,10)]+'-'+cdday+' - '+cdyear;flag=1;}
    if(showcommentnum==true)
    {if(flag==1){towrite=towrite+' | ';}
    if(commenttext=='1 Comments')commenttext='1 Comment';if(commenttext=='0 Comments')commenttext='No Comments';commenttext='<a href="'+commenturl+'" target ="_top">'+commenttext+'</a>';towrite=towrite+commenttext;flag=1;;}
    if(displaymore==true)
    {if(flag==1)towrite=towrite+' | ';towrite=towrite+'<a href="'+posturl+'" class="url" target ="_top">More »</a>';flag=1;}
    document.write(towrite);document.write('</li>');if(displayseparator==true)
    if(i!=(numposts-1))
    document.write('');}document.write('</ul>');}
    //]]>
    </script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>var numposts = 5;var showpostthumbnails = true;var displaymore = false;var displayseparator = true;var showcommentnum = false;var showpostdate = false;var showpostsummary = false;var numchars = 0;</script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/feeds/posts/default/-/newsy?published&alt=json-in-script&callback=labelthumbs"></script>
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try using `line-height` property on your css..

Comment: To be honest I need a little more information ;). What should I add and where?

Comment: On `.clearfix` i read your code, the gap space because you set `padding:12px` on all `li`, you can use `line-height` or just remove padding on `li.clearfix`